# How to keep counting after 4 rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I was provided with some code that a guy who is not longer available did. say you have a table with five columns.  the first four columns get filled with a query that works fine, then there is this piece of code that completes the fifth column. When I run it it gets me "Subscript out of range (Error 9)" when it goes for the fifth row and below. The 1,2,3 and 4 work ok. Any help would be great! The error is highlighted on the line above the fisrt "for"

```
    Function HorasSemana() As Double
        Dim sumaHoras As Double
        Dim lRow As Integer
        Dim semanas(1 To 4) As Integer

        lRow = DatosOmnia.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            semanas(i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(DatosOmnia.Cells(i, "C"), vbMonday)
            'MsgBox WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(DatosOmnia.Cells(i, "C"), vbMonday)
        Next i

        'lRow toma el valor con respecto a la hoja "Horas Semanales"
        lRow = Worksheets("Horas Semanales").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To sizeOf(semanas) '(UBound(semanas, 1) - LBound(semanas, 1) + 1)
            sumaHoras = 0
            For j = 2 To lRow
                If WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Worksheets("Horas Semanales").Cells(j, "B"), vbMonday) = semanas(i) Then
                    sumaHoras = sumaHoras + Worksheets("Horas Semanales").Cells(j, "C").Value
                    DatosOmnia.Cells(i + 1, "F") = sumaHoras
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        HorasSemana = sumaHoras
End Function
```

Comment: If you've got `Dim semanas(1 to 4)...`, then lRow can't be more then 5, otherwise `semanas(i - 1)` will throw that error. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: That is correct, I did not notice it. like i said, it was made by somebody else... how could I set that value acording to the amount of rows with information?

Comment: Change the code to Dim semanas(1 To 5) As Integer - or any other number that you wish... And since you're new to this, lookup arrays in VBA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize your array according to `lRow`:

```
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim semanas() As Long

    lRow = DatosOmnia.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim semanas(1 to lRow-1)
```

Typically `Long` is preferable to `Integer` - it doesn't "cost" more, and it's safer if your data grows larger